# django-tables2 linkColumn external url

Tags: django, django-tables2

I have 2 model attributes - model.name and model.url
I need to create a linkColumn that column name = model.name and link to the url specified in 
model.url

Is it possible to achieve such thing?

thanks

Comment: It's not clear: would you like to make a request or make some changes in your existing models?

Comment: I achieved it by creating a custom column that renders the link.

Comment: Found this question while looking for something similar. Added my solution as an answer.

Comment: I know this might be an old posting, but you can handle that by creating a view and redirect user to the external link. simple as that

Answer (score 11):

You can use TemplateColumn to achieve it. Your tables.py should look something like this

```
# yourapp/tables.py
import django_tables2 as tables
from yourapp.models import yourmodel
class YourTable(tables.Table):
    name = tables.TemplateColumn('<a href="{{record.url}}">{{record.name}}</a>')
    class Meta:
        model = yourmodel
        fields = ('name') # fields to display
```

You may refer to the [DOC](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#django_tables2.columns.TemplateColumn), for more info.

Comment: Been looking on how to do this for a long time! The documentation is not as clear as your example, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it by creating a custom column that queries the database and renders the link
from the given attributes